# How does Qemu locate its image file or How does Eclipse interact with Qemu?

Tags: eclipse, qemu

for studying Qemu I got the 'QEMU Eclipse' plugin, built the 'blinky' project from https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/tutorials/blinky-arm/ and when I let it run, it produces the following output:

```
    xPack 64-bit QEMU v2.8.0-9 (qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse).
    Board: 'STM32F4-Discovery' (ST Discovery kit for STM32F407/417 lines).
    Board picture: '/home/hgiese/Work/qemu-arm-dev/linux-x64/install/qemu-arm/share/qemu/graphics/STM32F4-Discovery.jpg'.
    Device file: '/home/hgiese/Work/qemu-arm-dev/linux-x64/install/qemu-arm/share/qemu/devices/STM32F40x-qemu.json'.
    Device: 'STM32F407VG' (Cortex-M4 r0p0, MPU, 4 NVIC prio bits, 82 IRQs), Flash: 1024 kB, RAM: 128 kB.
    Command line: 'blinky' (6 bytes).
```

...
and when I let it run everything was fine.
Now, when I called Qemu directly (outside of Eclipse) with the **exact command line** the output was this:

```
xPack 64-bit QEMU v2.8.0-9 (qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse).
Board: 'STM32F4-Discovery' (ST Discovery kit for STM32F407/417 lines).
Board picture: '/home/hgiese/Work/qemu-arm-dev/linux-x64/install/qemu-arm/share/qemu/graphics/STM32F4-Discovery.jpg'.
Device file: '/home/hgiese/Work/qemu-arm-dev/linux-x64/install/qemu-arm/share/qemu/devices/STM32F40x-qemu.json'.
Device: 'STM32F407VG' (Cortex-M4 r0p0, MPU, 4 NVIC prio bits, 82 IRQs), Flash: 1024 kB, RAM: 128 kB.
Command line: 'blinky' (6 bytes).
qemu-system-gnuarmeclipse: Guest image must be specified (using --image)
```

no matter how I specified 'blinky':

- being **in** the Debug directory
- calling it as blinky.elf
- calling it with its complete path

It got even stranger: In an attempt to produce an error message from Qemu (which might tell me something) I replaced 'blinky' with 'xyz' (in the command line field of the 'Debugger' pane in the 'Debug Configuration' dialog) - **and it still worked**. The only difference being the line

```
Command line: 'xyz' (3 bytes).
```

in Qemu's output, which showed me that Qemu had received this dummy parameter - and it didn't make the slightest difference for it: it still had the correct image file.
How do I have to communicate the image file to Qemu (or 'How does Eclipse does its magic?')
Any insight will be greatly appreciated.
Helmut